# Facebook API Multi-Friend Selector

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

i try send message to select friends, i found example 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/multi-friend-selector/v2.2
, but when i try send message, for example:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
   to: id,
   title: 'My Great Invite',
   message: 'Check out this Awesome App!'
});
```

where **id** is **Invite Token** i have error:

> does not resolve to a valid user ID

Thanks for your help.

Comment: And where did you get the token from?

Comment: I have token from /me/taggable_friends

Comment: And you got it using the same app? How “old” is the token, is it “fresh”? (Those tokens are only valid for a limited amount of time.)